# Open edX smtp email not being sent

Tags: python, email, smtp, bitnami, openedx

I have installed Open edX bitnami ami and now testing it. I want to send emails from the edX instance like registration confirmation email. I have followed the documentation here: [How to configure outbound email settings](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Open_edX#How_to_configure_outbound_email_settings.3f) I used mandrill smtp host instead of gmail. But I could not receive any mail as for some reason the configuration did not work. How can I configure the email settings? I also want to know where are the console email being logged and where to look for to solve email issues?

Answer (score 1):

I was just able to get it to work. Here's how I did this:

1. I followed the "Gmail SMTP" guide on the Bitnami Wiki for Open edX.
2. Make sure you replace all ocurrences of "smtp.gmail.com" by "smtp.mandrillapp.com" in all edX configuration files: lms.env.conf, lms.auth.conf, cms.env.conf, cms.auth.conf.
3. Change all the occurrences of EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD accordingly.
4. Restart Apache.
5. Test it, for example, log in and try to change your email address to a valid one. You should get a verification mail.

By the way, I've updated the Bitnami wiki including Mandrill configuration: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Open_edX#SMTP_configure_for_Mandrill (just updated, you should also add the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL field). Hope it helps.

Comment: Problem is, i did all these before posting the question. It didn't worked for some reason. There are no problem with mandrill credential or any other part of the configuration. still didn't receive any email. I want to track the reason why emails are not being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Change following attributes in `common.py` and `aws.py`

`django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` to

`django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`

Set the value in lms.env.json

`EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com",
 EMAIL_PORT="587", 
 EMAIL_HOST_USER="emailid",
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="password"` and 
`EMAIL_USE_TLS="true"`

then restart your edx
 `sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp:`

`sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp_worker:`

Comment: This post needs some editing. Could you highlite the code by using 'ctrl+K'?!

Comment: This answer sounds correct but have have received any point. Probaly on one have been able to try it. Can you specify the location of both common.py and aws.py